# Как сделать чтобы кнопка select folder удалилась после выполнения своей функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

при нажитии на `select folder` выбирается папка и путь пишется в `base.txt` (если он пуст) и создаются новые кнопки. Но `select folder` остается на заднем плане. Если путь уже записан в файле то она не создается и все нормально

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text, Label
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os


def but_dir():
    button_dir = Button(root, command=select, text='Select folder',
                        width=21, height=1, bg='grey',
                        fg='white', font="Arial 14")
    button_dir.place(x=10, y=20)


def but_run():
    button_run = Button(root, text="Run program",
                        width=21, height=1, bg='grey',
                        fg='white', font="Arial 14")
    button_run.place(x=10, y=40)


def but_edit():
    path = Label(root, font='Arial 11')
    path.place(x=9, y=7)
    path['text'] = open_path()

    button_dir = Button(root, command=select, text='Edit',
                        width=5, height=1, bg='grey',
                        fg='white', font="Arial 10")
    button_dir.place(x=201, y=5)

    but_run()


def select():
    folder = askdirectory() + '/'
    f = open('base.txt', 'w')
    f.write(folder)
    f.close()
    log.insert(1.0, 'Work folder: ' + folder)

    but_edit()


def open_path():
    f = open('base.txt')
    folder = f.read()
    f.close()
    return folder


root = Tk()

if os.path.getsize('base.txt') == 0:
    but_dir()
else:
    but_edit()

root.wm_title('Programm')
root.geometry("265x255")

log = Text(root, width=30, height=10)
log.place(x=10, y=85)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавьте вызов BUTTON.destroy() там, где нужно удалить кнопку

Comment: Вот подскажите мне, где же мне вызвать .destroy()? в функции but_edit()? как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обновите функцию but_dir:

```
BUTTON_SELECT_FOLDER = None     

def but_dir():
     button_dir = Button(root, command=select, text='Select folder',
                         width=21, height=1, bg='grey',
                         fg='white', font="Arial 14")
     button_dir.place(x=10, y=20)
     global BUTTON_SELECT_FOLDER
     BUTTON_SELECT_FOLDER = button_dir
```

Обновите функцию select:

```
def select():
    BUTTON_SELECT_FOLDER.destroy()
    folder = askdirectory() + '/'
    f = open('base.txt', 'w')
    f.write(folder)
    f.close()
    log.insert(1.0, 'Work folder: ' + folder)

    but_edit()
```

Comment: объясните, почему в select() это работает, а в but_edit() - нет

Comment: Обьясните подробней что работает, а что нет

Comment: Если я вызываю BUTTON_SELECT_FOLDER.destroy() не в select(), а в but_edit(), то вылетает ошибка

Comment: А вы убрали вызов из select? И что за ошибка?

Comment: да, из select убирал. вот ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: меня и в select устраивает, просто хочу понять почему в одной функции работает, а в другой - нет

Comment: уже разобрался, выходит что при первом запуске работает, а при последующих (если путь записан) - нет. Все потому, что кнопка не создается вообще и не может быть вызван ее метод) большое спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: Ох, на будущее сразу пишите в чем конкретно, и какая ошибка. Я бы сразу указал на проблему. А так все время потраченно на выяснение проблемы